# Local time was changed event (get change amount)

Tags: ios, swift, events, time

With the lines below it is possible to get a **notification on app launch that the system clock** (local device time) **was changed** by the user.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TimeWasChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.NSSystemClockDidChange, object: nil)


@objc func TimeWasChanged(){
    print("time was changed by the user!")        
}
```

I'm wondering if there is also a way to get notified **about the amount** the time value was changed (e.g. clock set **+10 minutes** *from 8:20pm to 8:30pm*).

---

If theres nothing like this already implemented would it be possible to calculate this offset manually (without using internet --> **No NHC or JSON**)?

Help would be very appreciated, Jane

Comment: Why did you remove the `objective-c` tag @rmaddy? I'm pretty sure for the solution of this question Swift&Objc must be combined.